# Searching a Class by User ForeignKey

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have searched high and low and even in between and for some reason cannot come up with a clear answer...

I am using `django1.9` and created this model:

```
class paymentInfo(models.Model):
    """
    Model for storing payment info
    - Username as ForeignKey from userToCard
    - Store payment token
    - Store last 4
    - Store card/bank name
    - Store bool value for Default method
    """

    username = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='username', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_4 = models.IntegerField()
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    class Meta:  # meta class to define the table name
        db_table = 'payment_methods'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Payment Methods'  # for the admin site display
        ordering = ('username',)

    def __str__(self):
        # in __str__  you should return a value of type string
        # so self.username changed to self.username.username          
        return self.username.username  # value displayed in admin view
```

I have created some objects using some different usernames and want to filter out the paymentInfo objects by user.

When I store the object, the database stores the `user pk` under the `username` column instead of the actual username string. I am not sure why, but that is not my issue here.

My issue is when I am trying to filter out `paymentInfo.objects` using the `username` or the `user pk`. I cannot seem to filter it out and the error I normally get is thus: `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: bank_name, default, id, last_4, token`

P.S. I am using MySQL

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: `ForeignKey` stores id of the linked model, if your field/db_column name for the `ForeignKey` relationship is `username` that does not mean it will magically start storing username in database. Better is to use the name of the model as field name e.g. `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, Amir. I will go ahead and make that change. As far as migrations, yes. How exactly would I search? The ‘pk’ is ‘21’ so I’ve tried various methods of searching to filter and that is when I receive my error above.

Comment: According to the docs, there is no need to have the `db_column` keyword argument:

`The name of the database column to use for this field. If this isn’t given, Django will use the field’s name.`

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Comment: Thank you pixeld, something that I picked up from other answers. Will remove :)

Comment: Happy to help in any way, @M.Gilbert :)

Comment: Considering you have applied my suggestion changing `username` to `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`. Then this should work `paymentInfo.objects.filter(user_id=21)` make sure your model is in sync with db that is why i am recommending to re-run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: Awesome, @Aamir. I will double check this when I hop on my PC

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you are trying to filter data by username from table User what is a foreign key. In this case, this should help

`paymentInfo.objects.filter(username__name='John')`

Comment: I will try this when I get back on my PC. Issue is, however, when I try and use ‘username’ as a keyword, I get the error as posted above ‘cannot resolve keyword username’

Comment: You need to use username__name as the keyword as it is spanning a FK relationship.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships This from documentations

Comment: Thank you kyle & AndMar for the quick responses. Will check these suggestions out ASAP!

Comment: So this did not work as I continued receiving the error of `cannot resolve keyword username`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers provided, I was able to work out a solution (mainly using @Aamir Adnan 's method.)

```
class paymentInfo(models.Model):
"""
Model for storing payment info
- Username as ForeignKey from userToCard
- Store payment token
- Store last 4
- Store card/bank name
- Store bool value for Default method
"""

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
token = models.CharField(max_length=10)
last_4 = models.IntegerField()
bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
default = models.BooleanField(default=0)

class Meta:  # meta class to define the table name
    db_table = 'payment_methods'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Payment Methods'  # for the admin site display
    ordering = ('user',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user  # value displayed in admin view

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.user)
```

The new `__unicode__` inside of my class was so that I did not receive this error anymore:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User found
```